# Kubernetes not using docker registry

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have kubernetes cluster with 7 worker nodes running behind proxy. Deploying application on cluster and scaling application is consuming too much of internet bandwidth. Therefore I decided to deploy Docker Registry acting as pull through cache server. But deployments are not pulling images from the registry. What is the issue here?

Docker `daemon.json`

```
...
"registry-mirrors": [
  "https://myregistry",
  "https://myregistry:443"
]
```

Docker version

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           20.10.5
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        55c4c88
 Built:             Tue Mar  2 20:33:55 2021
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.14
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       5eb3275d40
  Built:            Tue Dec  1 19:19:17 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.4.3
  GitCommit:        269548fa27e0089a8b8278fc4fc781d7f65a939b
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc92
  GitCommit:        ff819c7e9184c13b7c2607fe6c30ae19403a7aff
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

Kubernetes version

```
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v1.18.15", GitCommit:"73dd5c840662bb066a146d0871216333181f4b64", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-01-13T13:14:05Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"
```

---

Docker registry configuration

```
version: 0.1
log:
  fields:
    service: registry
storage:
  cache:
    blobdescriptor: inmemory
  filesystem:
    rootdirectory: /data
http:
  addr: :5000
  headers:
    X-Content-Type-Options: [nosniff]
health:
  storagedriver:
    enabled: true
    interval: 10s
    threshold: 3
proxy:
  remoteurl: https://index.docker.io/v1/
```

Comment: How did you deploy Docker Registry? Have you created persistent volume and service?

Comment: I have deployed registry on other host with docker-compose, I have updated the question again with current registry configuration yaml

Comment: It seems to me that API server can not see your docker service.

Comment: Can you elaborate that?

Answer (score 0):

To access the Docker Registry, your Kubernetes cluster needs to be able to make an outbound connection to the registry. If your proxy server is blocking this connection, then the deployments will not be able to retrieve the images from the registry. You may need to configure your proxy server to allow outbound connections to the registry.

The API server is not able to access any of the services running inside of the Docker container. This could be due to a misconfiguration or a firewall blocking the connection. In order for the API server to access the services running inside the container, it needs to have access to the Docker daemon, which is responsible for managing the containers. In order to allow the API server to access the Docker services deployed registry on another host with docker-compose, you will need to configure the appropriate ports to be accessible from the API server. You will need to open port 2375 on the Docker host, which is the default port used by the Docker Remote API. Additionally, you will need to ensure that port 5000 is open on the Docker host, as this is the default port used by the Docker Registry. Once you have opened up the necessary ports, you should be able to access the Docker services deployed registry on the Docker host from the API server.

Set the [imagePullPolicy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#updating-images) to Never, otherwise Kubernetes will try to download the image.

Refer to this [document](https://docs.docker.com/registry/recipes/mirror/) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for your response. My environment is I have 1 server running docker registry for pull through cache and kubernetes cluster nodes. In my understanding, any pod will be using it's allocated hosts docker daemon to pull the image and create the container. The problem is I can pull images through the registry from the worker node's command line. But pod cannot be created because it can't pull images through the registry. What might be the issue?

Comment: Kubernetes will attempt to pull images from the registry specified in the Pod spec, and if it is unable to pull the image, it will fail to create the Pod.add the following line to the Pod `spec:imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"`. This will tell Kubernetes to check the node's local Docker daemon first, and if the image is not present, it will pull it from the registry.

Comment: Make sure the credentials for the registry are correct, and that the nodes can access the registry. Additionally, make sure that the Pod has the correct permissions to access the registry. If the permissions are incorrect, the Pod may not be able to pull the image from the registry. Finally, make sure that the image is correctly tagged in the registry, as this can also cause issues with the Pod not being able to pull the image.

Comment: So the images that I'm going to pull has to already exist in the registry? What I'm trying to achieve here is that the worker pods use pull through registry to pull image so that all worker nodes doesn't have to pull same image if the image doesn't exist on the worker node. This will help me to reduce the bandwidth

Comment: Yes, the images that you want to pull must already exist in the registry in order to use pull through registry. Pull through registry can help reduce the amount of bandwidth needed to pull the same image to multiple worker nodes, as it will only pull the image once and then share it with the other nodes. However, it is important to note that the registry must be available and accessible to the nodes in order for the pull through registry to be successful.

Comment: Ah, I thought it can pull the images if the requested image does not exists..